Open channel flow meter stop reading the flow there is alarm, pipe empty
I am working in wastewater treatment plant ,open channel flow meter stop reading the flow,there is an alarm 'empty pipe''

If you have an empty pipe alarm then respond to it.

wouldn't an empty pipe have zero flow?

you forgot to ask a question ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Truly empty pipes can cause some serious priming issues. If the sensor is truly faulty, replace it to get treatment going again asap. If the pipe is truly empty, figure out what caused that...

An "open channel flow meter" usually means metering something like a trough or gutter, not a pipe or enclosed tube.
Open channel flow heights are often sensed by ultrasonic transducers or by hydrostatic pressure sensors.
Those raw input levels are usually converted to a mass flow level by a program or mechanism in the instrument.
During installation & setup an overall range of measurement is set.
Readings above or below that 'valid' range will report as an 'error' or 'malfunction'.
e.g. If flow height setup range = 50~100 but the actual flowing height = 35 then the meter will show 0 flow or error out as 'no flow'.
Maybe it was a programming mistake.
Maybe the transducer or sensor has been moved out of the correct position.
Maybe WW solids or rags have clogged the pressure sensor or it's port.
As a check, or standby method, a measuring stick and set of flow tables or algebra formulas for that particular shape and size of channel can provide reliable and reasonably accurate flow measurements.
That is how we calibrated or made emergency flow measurements before I retired over ten years ago.
Things have undoubtedly advanced since then; Lasers? Lidar?
We used the tables and formulas found in the Open_Channel_Flow_Handbook.
Those flow tables and formulas are likely available on today's internet.
Also check wastewater forums and manufacturer webpages.
Hope this helps.
EDIT by SK: The Transducer or Sensor may be faulty or disconnected from the Controller/Readout unit.
Not a common fault but it still happens on occasion.
